# Run .ispac programmatically in .NET fails in MSTest

Tags: c#, .net, ssis

I need to run an SSIS package (an .ispac file) from C# in a TestMethod. I use the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Project object to load the .ispac file, and execute a package from there. My tests only pass in Resharper, and in MSTest Debug mode. I need to get it working in none-debug mode so that I can run the test in the build-deploy-test workflow.

Under the same solution, I have 2 projects. The first project has the wrapper for the .ispac file. The second is the test project that references the first project, and invokes methods of the first project to run the SSIS package. The .ispac file is an external resource.

Any idea why the test runs are not consitent?

Thanks

PS: I have created a console application that mimic the test methods, but I have no issue both in debug and none-debug modes.

Comment: Are there any windows credentials ( especially impersonisation) being used?

Comment: Everything is Windows Credentials.

Comment: I should add that the tests ALWAYS pass in DEBUG mode.
In none-debug mode, the tests pass right after the previous debug run, and ALWAYS fail after that.